# How can i fix URL rewrite problem with Local copy of Magento store?

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, localhost, mamp

I have installed a new copy of Magento on my mac with MAMP - it's all working fine, I then copied my template files and modules that i created. All good. then we I go to import the live websites SQL database all the products appear and all the custom elements - however if i then click on a product that is on the home page (Or any other page for that matter) the URL's are wrong.

I have changed the base URL in the database to reflect my local install.

For reference my local copy is set up as so: http://localhost:8888/magento which works fine. now when i click on a product (from the home page) it tries to go to http://localhost:8888/product-name-here - so it misses off the /magento/ part.

But even if i make manually type in http://localhost:8888/magento/product-name-here i get a 404 not found error (and not a magento 404 error?)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you also tried `http://localhost:8888/magento/index.php/product-name-here`? Did you make any changes to the `.htaccess` file? Were you following a migration guide that explained any necessary database changes?

Comment: I was trying a couple of different guides! I did try the above url - it still didn't work. I did make changes to my live .htaccess - but then I also copied that file across to my local copy and it still didn't work.. thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your base URL for secure and unsecure has your subdirectory (magento) in it.

`http://localhost:8888/magento`

Comment: Don't forget the slash .../magento/

Answer (score 0):

Please update your secure and insecure url in magento admin like these
http://localhost:8888/magento/.Please make your catalog rewriting is set to No. After that please update indexing in admin. This is routing problem.please don't forget to update indexing in admin after you have done these settings.